# Python Web API Package for Pylons

Tags: api, pylons, package

Hey guys,
I've decided on Pylons (with SQLAlchemy) for my web application.
My web application basically provides an API for fetching data in JSON. Other than that, I have a constantly running backend side that fetches data 24/7. This backend is sequenced with Celery.
Are there any packages like Piston for django for creating API's easily (OAuth, JSON emission) for Pylons?
Thanks!